# Personal postfix mail server works, but i can't connect it with thunderbird

Tags: server, email, thunderbird, postfix, mail

I recently setup my self postfix on my remote dedicated server.
I got the postfix running and it's able to send and receive messages from outside.

My problem is that I can't login to this mail server using for example thunderbird. When I try to add this mail server to thunderbird it just fails with error message:

`failed to find the settings for your email account`

[Telnet login result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OYjU.png)

Is there something I still need to do or what could cause this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What authentication and encryption settings did you have tbird set to?  And I don't see a username/login command in your telnet session.

Comment: i'm trying to use STARTTLS on both IMAP and SMTP with normal password

Comment: It doesn't look like you used either of those in your telnet session.

Answer (score 0):

Go to account configuration on thunderbird and click on Edit server SMTP and there you have auth method. My problem was that my server was non-auth but on my thunderbird auth method was different.